# Recomplile VueJS / Vite

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vite

I lost my resources files by thunderstorm / SSD broken. In my last commit and push all compiled files was inlcuded in GIT.

Is there a way to recompile this JS files to VueJs...?

Comment: Search for source map decompilation, in case you have them. Project config cannot be recovered this way